# Boostrap Dropdown Active with External Header

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I add the boostrap "active" class to my navbar on an external header, my header code is this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../assets/img/logo_white.png" style="height: 35px;"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    About
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="about/about-us.html">About Us</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="about/staff.html">Staff Team</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="about/partners.html">Partners</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Resources
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="resources/downloads.html">Downloads</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="resources/charts.html">Charts</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="resources/metar.html">METAR Decoder</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="academy/index.html">Academy</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Fly</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://forums.multicrew.co.uk/">Forums</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://multicrew.setmore.com/">Book</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

For example if I navigate to the page about/about-us I would want the active class to be added to both the li dropdown menu "about" and then the actual dropdown "about-us" bearing in mind that I am using an external header the file being /header.html. How could I do it?

If I'm right in saying I would need to use jQuery or php, how would I implement this?

**EDIT**
I have tried to use the Vitaa ActiveNavigation jQuery plugin [found here](https://github.com/Vitaa/ActiveNavigation) but to no luck

Thanks

Comment: if I understand correctly, you would do that with a server side language or with js by reading url structure

Comment: Do you have any ideas of the code that I would have to use, I have tried different examples but none work

Comment: Are these static pages or are you using a backend language such as php or asp.net ?

Comment: They are just static html pages

Comment: Any ideas anyone, really need to fix this